# How to show variable values when debug java in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I debug a simple java application on Eclipse in debug as and step into java resource bundle which got interrupted exception in line construction.getCause

How do I trace each variable and express to see the values from java library?
In j2ee, I can point mice at params, vars and assigned value from express, how do I see it in java application?

Why it cannot find the resource MyBundle base for MyBundle_zh.properties under project src?

Screen shot: https://plus.google.com/collection/UFuOlB
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ibrMgi8udPlaAIvyvPKc4tE5Agw5SzXxi5yp0a3yZJA5zNkYymSPgFHUEsO_tD2HsDMUZzE2=w640-h360-p-rw
Thanks[image]

Comment: Why take a low quality smartphone photo and transfer that from your phone to your pc, if you can just press the PRINT SCREEN button (Prt Scr) on your keyboard and get a high quality screenshot?

Comment: Load from app, can't delete, find the link or google plus my collections

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse has different Perspectives, you can switch them from Window -> Show Perspective. Each Perspective can have a different set of views. In you case, make sure that you have the Debug Perspective open and then (if you don't have it there already) do:

Window -> Show View -> Variables

Then, when your execution stops on a set breakpoint, you will be able to inspect all the relevant variables in the "Variables" view.

Comment: I saw the variable view, it has a few args and variable values, but I want to see each step and the result of it.

Comment: Not sure what "rags" means but if you step over each line, you should see all the variables you need.

Comment: Args. I did, it doesn't display the value of those variables on each line. I right clich to inspect, it shows an error

Comment: Maybe if you attach a screenshot it will be more clear to understand.

Comment: How to load it? It only says what variable it is, not showing any value.

Comment: Load what? The screenshot can be uploaded by editing your original question.

Comment: Added after shrink it.

Comment: Sorry but this is unreadable. Can't you just do a screenshot with a PrtScn button and crop it? Or use Greenshot or similar software?

Comment: (PrtSc copies the current screen to the clipboard. You can then paste it into Paint and save it to disk.)

Comment: See the link of the image in the answer since app and peer review not convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Your **Installed JREs** preference page, project **Java Build Paths**, and launch configurations should not be using "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\jre". They should instead just point to "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04", after which the Java platform sources will be shown and debugging features you expect will work more automatically.